# Where to declare variable in react

Tags: reactjs

i wanted to ask what is the most appropriate place to declare a variable in rect: constructor, render or componentDidUpdate? I am really confused in this.I wanted to render the value of a variable, for which i had to declare it somewhere. I have kept my logic inside componentDidMount:

```
componentDidMount(){
let seasonupdate ='';
console.log('this.props.LAT:', this.props.lat )
    if(this.props.lat > 0 ){
        //console.log('this.checkMonth(): ',this.checkMonth(), 'N. Hemis' )
        if(12 >= this.checkMonth() >=9){
            console.log('N. Hemis and winter')
            seasonupdate = <div>N. Hemis and winter</div>

        }else{
            console.log('N. Hemis and summer') 
            seasonupdate = <div>N. Hemis and summer</div>
        }
     }

     if(this.props.lat < 0 ){
      //  console.log('this.checkMonth(): ',this.checkMonth(), 'S. Hemis' )

        if(12 >= this.checkMonth() >=9){
            console.log('S. Hemis and summer')
             seasonupdate = <div>S. Hemis and summer</div>
        }else{
            console.log('S. Hemis and winter') 
             seasonupdate = <div>S. Hemis and winter</div>
        }

     }
}
```

Render function is like this:

```
render(props) {


        return (
            <div>
                seasondisplay: {this.props.lat}
                <br/>
               Season update: {this.seasonupdate}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

I get the error in here: `Season update: {this.seasonupdate}`, saying: 'seasonupdate' is assigned a value but never used . Please help where i should initialize my variable.

Answer (score 0):

try below

```
render(props) {
    const {seasonupdate} = this.state          
    return (
        <div>
            seasondisplay: {this.props.lat}
            <br/>
           Season update: {this.seasonupdate}
        </div>
    )
}
```

you can define the variable in constructor

Comment: is there any issue?

Comment: Yes. the code in the question doesn't use state anywhere

Comment: we can try it assign to a state and use it.. what is going to be your answer @Aditya

Comment: can easily done with state why this guy type this much of code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make `seasonUpdate` a state.

```js
class ComponentName extends React.Component {
  state = {
    seasonUpdate: null
  }
}
```

Therefore, if you want to update the value of the property, you can assign the value like so.

```
this.setState({ seasonUpdate: <div>N. Hemis and winter</div> })
```

Broader example.

```js
componentDidMount() {
  const { lat } = this.props 
  if (lat > 0 ) {
    if (12 >= this.checkMonth() >= 9){
      this.setState({ seasonUpdate: <div>N. Hemis and winter</div> })
    } else {
      this.setState({ seasonUpdate: <div>N. Hemis and summer</div> })
    }
  } else {
    if (12 >= this.checkMonth() >= 9) {
      this.setState({ seasonUpdate: <div>S. Hemis and summer</div> })
    } else {
      this.setState({ seasonUpdate: <div>S. Hemis and winter</div> })
    }
  }
}
```

Using state ensures that re-rendering will occur, thus showing the updated value instead of the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

The best place to store a variable when you need to update it on the `componentDidMount` is to do it on a `State`, this way you could update your variable without any problem and  display it on the `render` method, as shown:

```
state = {
  seasonUpdate: '' 
};

componentDidMount() {
  console.log('this.props.LAT:', this.props.lat );

  if(this.props.lat > 0 ) {
    if(12 >= this.checkMonth() >=9) {
      console.log('N. Hemis and winter');
        this.setState({ seasonUpdate: (<div>N. Hemis and winter</div>) });
    } else {
        console.log('N. Hemis and summer') 
        this.setState({ seasonUpdate: (<div>N. Hemis and summer</div>) });
    }
  }

  if(this.props.lat < 0 ) {
    //  console.log('this.checkMonth(): ',this.checkMonth(), 'S. Hemis' )
    if(12 >= this.checkMonth() >=9) {
      console.log('S. Hemis and summer')
      this.setState({ seasonUpdate: (<div>S. Hemis and summer</div>) });
    } else {
      console.log('S. Hemis and winter') 
      this.setState({ seasonUpdate: (<div>S. Hemis and winter</div>) });
    }
  }
}

render() {
  const { lat } = this.props; 
  const { seasonUpdate } = this.state;
  return (
    <div>
      seasondisplay: {lat}
      <br/>
      Season update: {seasonUpdate}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Hope this helps.